# RecyclerView Scroll Listener with few items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onscrolllistener

What I am trying to achieve is a load more on RecyclerView when I scroll up. I have the implementation for scroll down and it works fine. I modified the same implementation for scroll up. It works when my RecyclerView has a lot of items. However, if my RecyclerView only has 1 or 2 items, the onScroll method for the RecyclerView never gets called. Is there any work around for this scenario? How can I load more on scroll up if there are only a few items in the RecyclerView.

Here is the code that I use for scroll up/down to load more

```
mAppointmentList.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

        if (dy > 0) {
            Log.i("SCROLLING", "DOWN");

        } else if (dy < 0) {
            Log.i("SCROLLING", "UP");
        }
    }
);
```

When I have 1 or 2 items in my RecyclerView, it never scrolls up. How can I scroll up in this scenario?

**EDIT**
My RecyclerView is in a fragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".fragment.AppointmentListFragment">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/appointment_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="8dp" />
</FrameLayout>
```

The item layout is also pretty simple.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    android:elevation="4dp">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/status_dot"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="\u2022"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/status"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/status"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/status" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/date_container"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/date_view"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/title"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline2">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/day"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_regular"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Feb, 01"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/month"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_regular"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="2019"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="16sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideline2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.33" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_regular"
            android:text="SQA"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline2"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/status"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_regular"
            android:text="UNPAID"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/title"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_regular"
            android:text="Imran Aftab"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/date_container"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/date_container" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_regular"
            android:text="02:00 AM"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/name"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/name" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/length"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_regular"
            android:text="Length: 01 hr 00 mins"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/date_container"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/time"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/time"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/price"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/round_text"
            android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_regular"
            android:paddingStart="8dp"
            android:paddingTop="4dp"
            android:paddingEnd="8dp"
            android:paddingBottom="4dp"
            android:text="$100"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/date_container"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/status"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/status"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/private_label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/round_text"
            android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_regular"
            android:paddingStart="8dp"
            android:paddingTop="4dp"
            android:paddingEnd="8dp"
            android:paddingBottom="4dp"
            android:text="Private"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/price"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/price"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/price" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

[image: The state in which I want to scroll up]

Comment: Share your recyclerview item xml, and main xml where you are adding recyclerview.

Comment: @TheAnkush please check the latest edit

Comment: @BilalNaeem do you meant pagination when recycler view reached bottom?

Comment: @RajasekaranM not really. What I want to do is to load data when the user scrolls up. Like I mentioned in the question, this does happen when the list has a lot of items. But when the list has only 1 or 2 items, the scroll never occurs.

Comment: yes because you recycler not much for scroll

Comment: @RajasekaranM when I am at the top of my list and I scroll up, the scroll does not happen, so no callback is fired. I want this to happen so I can use it to load data.

Comment: did you tried setting recyclerviews height to wrap_content?

Comment: @KaranMer just tried it. Still the same.

Answer (score 0):

So the way I finally achieved it was to use the fling listener. I checked whether or not the fling was going up and checked if my recyclerview could be scrolled that way. If it couldn't then I was at the top of my list and could just load more items. This works even if my list only has 1 item (other methods which rely on scroll listener don't work in this scenario).

Here is the code that I used

```
mAppointmentList.setOnFlingListener(new RecyclerView.OnFlingListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onFling(int i, int i1) {
        if (!mAppointmentList.canScrollVertically(-1) && i1 < 0) {
            //Fetch items here
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

I am returning false because this is just a check if the user is trying to scroll up. This might not be the best way to do this but its what worked for me.